# Marker line in CartoCSS

Tags: qgis, carto, cartocss

I'm trying to symbolize a line layer in CartoDB using CartoCSS. I need my line to be a series of diagonal lines, something like this -> /////////////

In QGIS I would do this as a marker line with a straight line set at an angle for the marker. However, I can't figure out whether such functionality is present in CartoCSS. I can't see anything in the documentation for marker lines. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to take a look at this nice tutorial about styling lines in CartoCSS: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-lines/

I have done some tests in my CartoDB account, and this CartoCSS does something similar to what you need to obtain:

```
#untitled_table {
  ::line, ::hatch { line-color: #FF6600; }
  ::line { line-width:0; }
  ::hatch {
    line-width: 4;
    line-dasharray: 1, 4;
  }
}
```

[image: Dashed line]

If you need something more custom, you might want to try with the parameter `line-pattern-file` in CartoCSS to add your own pattern as the tutorial suggests :-)

Comment: Thanks. That's the solution I've settled on, but it doesn't give me the ability to slant the hatches, so my line looks like this ||||||| instead of like this ///////.

Comment: What about using your own pattern file with a "/" marker?

Comment: I tried creating a pattern file with a diagonal line but it was blurred. I suppose there are probably tweaks I could make to get that method to work, but it seems like being able to define a marker line is obvious missing functionality. One shouldn't have to create a pattern file for a simple repeating marker.